# iOS - IBAction - in which text field the user is typing

Tags: iphone, ios, button, click, ibaction

I have 2 text fields in my app and both are connected with my "devTyping" IBAction.
This method (I guess it is a method) will be called when the event "editing changed" happens.

How can I tell my method, in which text field the user is typing?

```
- (IBAction)devTyping {
    NSLog(@"How to know in which text field the user is typing?");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542327/how-to-define-which-button-pressed-if-they-both-have-same-ibaction), which should be an equivalent as to what you are asking :)

Comment: Exactly so—I'd go with the tag option. Checking for integer equality on something that you're probably never going to change/look at again is better than using an arbitrary method on the instance variables of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the method like this:

```
- (IBAction)devTyping:(UITextField*)sender {
     NSLog(@"The user is typing in text field %d",sender.tag);
}
```

And assign each textfield a `tag` in Interface Builder, which is just a number to identify the text field (or any other element).