# Linking multiple buttons to one method with different jobs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods

I have a huge crazy scene in my story board that has 36 different buttons, and each one means something different when clicked on. I really don't want to go about creating 36 different methods, so how could I reference a button title or button name in a method that is called when one of the 36 buttons is pushed.

This is probably a simple question, but I'm new to iOS and Objective C...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858247/ios-one-ibaction-for-multiple-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each button a unique tag value. in the IBAction, sender.tag tells you which button was tapped.

Comment: hmm... try (IBAction)the_action:(UIButton*)sender...  and then [sender tag]

Comment: tag is a property inherited from UIView, it's an int. This will work.  Set your UIButton's tag value in IB or in code with `button.tag = 501`;  set the UIButton's action to your handler. Change the parameter type to UIButton* so `-(IBAction)the_handler:(UIButton*)sender`.  Now, `int x = [sender tag];` should work.

Comment: Using a tag is better than using the title.  The title may change with a GUI update or with localization.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a single method, like so:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender{

  // The button that was tapped is called "sender"
  // This will log out the title of the button

  //NSLog(@"Button: %@", sender.titleLabel.text);

  //Edit: You need a cast in the above line of code:

  NSLog(@"Button: %@", ((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel.text);
}
```

Then, you can use Interface Builder to connect to all of the buttons. You can have some sort of if/else logic to test which button was tapped.

You can check the titleLabel property, or you can assign an `IBOutlet` to each button and check for that.

For example:

```
if([sender isEqual:buttonOutlet1]){
  //If this button is attached to buttonOutlet1
  //do something
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply use the label of each button, not worrying about outlets.

A third option would be to generate and lay out the buttons in code, and then access them as elements of an array of buttons.

A fourth option would be to add tags to the buttons and check for the button's tag in your function.

Comment: That works, but then I would have to go about creating outlets for each button.

Comment: @JoeBurnett - Or you can use the titleLabel or use an array.

Comment: When I do this... NSLog(@"Button: %@", sender.titleLabel.text); --- I get this error... Property 'titleLabel' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: @JoeBurnett You need to cast the sender to UIButton, since it's visible to the method with the type `id`. See my edit.

Comment: Would it not be more efficient to do a pointer comparison in your last example as you want to know if it is the exact same object e.g. pointing to the same address

Comment: @Paul.s You may be right, I was just illustrating the basics. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The IBAction routine you set up to handle the button presses has a `sender` parameter.  Examine that to decide.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite simple, but since you're new, here's an answer.

(According to Stanford cs193p course, 2010-2011 fall (that's what they did with the calculator app)) make a method that receives an argument, which is the UIButton. 
for example:

```
- (IBAction) someMethodThatDoesSomething:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Then make if statements according to the `sender.titleLabel.text`

I don't know if there are any other solutions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) buttonPress: (id) sender {
    UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *buttonTitle = [pressedButton currentTitle];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString: @"SomeTitle"]) {
        //do work for that button.
    }
}
```

You can use a variety of NSString methods to compare or filter which button was pressed and handle it through if's or switches.

Answer (score 0):

-(IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender {

```
    if ([sender tag] == 0) {
        // do something here
    }
    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        // Do some think here
   }

}
```

// in Other words

-(IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender {

```
     NSLog(@"Button Tag is : %i",[sender tag]);

    switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 0:
        // Do some think here
        break;
    case 1:
       // Do some think here
         break;
   default:
       NSLog(@"Default Message here");
        break;
```

}