# Multiple buttons segue to the same view controller with unique identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue, ibaction

I have a ViewControllerA that has roughly 15 buttons in my case they represent levels, When a level is pressed it segues to ViewControllerB. Now it doesn't make sense to manually ctrl+drag and create segue for each button. I'm wondering how can a button segue to ViewControllerB and have a unique identifier then ill be passing an object in other words data to ViewControllerB to recognize which level the user pressed. I also want to point out that I have a push view controller.
So far one of my unsuccessful attempts were to do is to ctrl+drag all the buttons and create a method called:(the button title in my case is the level number)

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:[sender currentTitle] sender:self];  
}
```

afterwards I call the `prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender` method.To be honest Im new to iOS developing. Any helpful tutorial or article would be great for me.
Thanks in advance for all helpers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were close with your unsuccessful attempt. You only want one identifier for a single segue that you set up in IB directly from the controller to VCB. In your action method, that all the button's invoke, do this (notice that I'm passing the button in the sender argument):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:sender];  
}
```

Then in prepareForSegue, you can use the sender argument to get the button's title:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender {
        NSString *title = sender.currentTitle;
        // do what you need with the title
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply I'm truly sorry if this question may disturb your but I didn't get the part when you said: "set up in IB directly from the controller to VCB"

Comment: @Oneill Your segue should be linked from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`, rather than from any of the buttons.

Comment: @nhgrif ok ill be trying this very soon once I get home. thank you very much for the quick response appreciate it!

Comment: @Oneill There is a little bar underneath the scene in IB. When you select that, you'll see three icons in that bar. The leftmost one is the view controller. Control-drag from that view controller icon underneath the first view scene to the next scene. Then give that segue a unique identifier, in rdelmar's example, `MySegueIdentifier` (by selecting the segue and going to the "Attributes" inspector).

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a private property on `ViewControllerA` (perhaps using an enum) to make note of which level is selected.
2. In your `- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender` method, you need to figure out which button was pressed, and use that information to set the property.  Then call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfStoryboardSegue" sender:self];`
3. Create a public property on `ViewControllerB` to keep track of which level is selected.
4. Override the `prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender` method.  Instantiate the destination view controller as a `ViewControllerB`, and set the property on B to match the selected property from A.
5. Perform the segue.

This [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object) will help you with passing the data between views in the `prepareForSegue` method, and this [question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858247/ios-one-ibaction-for-multiple-buttons) might help with handling all the buttons in the single `IBAction` method.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply ill be trying this once I get home. and I'll comment my feedback very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found a simple solution...

duplicate the View Controller from your storyboard and assign the same class to it in identity inspector. You will have a duplicate "storyboard view controller" connected to the same code. With its own icon, tag and storyboard ID