# How do I fix this code that executes but does not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, sprite-kit

I created lots of UIButtons and I connected them to the IBOutlets but also I connected a IBAction to all of these UIButtons.

But the other codes those include these buttons, doesn't work. Code gets executed but doesn't work. Xcode doesn't give an error also.

How can I fix this issue?

By the way here are the translations:

- salise = split second
- saniye = second
- dakika = minute

GameController.m (View Controller);

```
`#import "GameController.h"
#import "GameButtons.h

@class UIButton;
@interface GameController ()

@end
@implementation GameController
@synthesize firstlabel, timelabel,running,selected;
@synthesize button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,button10;
@synthesize button11,button12,button13,button14,button15,button16,button17,button18,button19,button20;
@synthesize button21,button22,button23,button24,button25,button26,button27,button28,button29,button30;
@synthesize button31,button32,button33,button34,button35,button36,button37,button38,button39,button40;
@synthesize button41,button42,button43,button44,button45,button46,button47,button48,button49,startButton;
int salise = 0;
int saniye = 0;
int dakika = 0;
int down = 3;
bool countdownOnline;
-(IBAction)buttonGame:(id)sender{
    selected=sender;
    if ([selected.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonRed.png"]]) {
        int random = arc4random()%(50-0);
        [[GameButtons selectedButton:random] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonRed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        running=NO;
    }

}
-(IBAction)buttonStart:(id)sender{
    running = YES;
    countdownOnline=YES;
    [timelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", down]];
    down--;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countdown:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [firstlabel setText:@""];
    startButton.enabled=NO;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updateTime:(NSTimer*)timer{
    if (countdownOnline==NO){
    NSString *fulltime;
    NSString *strSalise;
    salise++;
    if (salise==100) {
        salise=0;
        saniye++;
        if (saniye==60) {
            saniye=0;
            dakika++;
        }
        strSalise = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",salise];
    }
    else if (salise <10) {
        strSalise = [@"0" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",salise]];
    }
    else{
        strSalise = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",salise];
    }
    NSLog(@"time done");
    fulltime = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dakika] stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    fulltime = [fulltime stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",saniye]];
    fulltime = [fulltime stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    fulltime = [fulltime stringByAppendingString:strSalise];
    [timelabel setText:fulltime];
    }
    else if (running==NO){
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    else{}
}
-(void)countdown:(NSTimer*)timer{
    if (down>0) {
        [timelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",down]];
        down--;
    }
    else if (down==0){
        [timelabel setText:@"GO!"];
        down--;
    }
    else if(down<0){
        [timer invalidate];
        countdownOnline=NO;
        int random = (arc4random()%1)+49;
        [[GameButtons selectedButton:random] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonRed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [GameButtons makebuttonsPressable];
    }
    NSLog(@"Countdown done.");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [GameButtons makebuttonsUnpressable];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end`
```

GameButtons.m (My Class);

```
#import "GameButtons.h"
#import "GameController.h"

@implementation GameButtons
+(UIButton*)selectedButton:(int)intran{
    UIButton *button;
    GameController *gmc =[[GameController alloc]init];
    if (intran==0){
        button = gmc.button1;
    }
    else if (intran==1){
        button = gmc.button2;
    }
    else if (intran==2){
        button = gmc.button3;
    }
    else if (intran==3){
        button = gmc.button4;
    }
    else if (intran==4){
        button = gmc.button5;
    }
    else if (intran==5){
        button = gmc.button6;
    }
    else if (intran==6){
        button = gmc.button7;
    }
    else if (intran==7){
        button = gmc.button8;
    }
    else if (intran==8){
        button = gmc.button9;
    }
    else if (intran==9){
        button = gmc.button10;
    }
    else if (intran==10){
        button = gmc.button11;
    }
    else if (intran==11){
        button = gmc.button12;
    }
    else if (intran==12){
        button = gmc.button13;
    }
    else if (intran==13){
        button = gmc.button14;
    }
    else if (intran==14){
        button = gmc.button15;
    }
    else if (intran==15){
        button = gmc.button16;
    }
    else if (intran==16){
        button = gmc.button17;
    }
    else if (intran==17){
        button = gmc.button18;
    }
    else if (intran==18){
        button =gmc.button19;
    }
    else if (intran==19){
        button = gmc.button20;
    }
    else if (intran==20){
        button = gmc.button21;
    }
    else if (intran==21){
        button = gmc.button22;
    }
    else if (intran==22){
        button = gmc.button23;
    }
    else if (intran==23){
        button = gmc.button24;
    }
    else if (intran==24){
        button = gmc.button25;
    }
    else if (intran==25){
        button = gmc.button26;
    }
    else if (intran==26){
        button =gmc.button27;
    }
    else if (intran==27){
       button = gmc.button28;
    }
    else if (intran==28){
        button = gmc.button29;
    }
    else if (intran==29){
        button = gmc.button30;
    }
    else if (intran==30){
        button = gmc.button31;
    }
    else if (intran==31){
        button = gmc.button32;
    }
    else if (intran==32){
        button = gmc.button33;
    }
    else if (intran==33){
        button = gmc.button34;
    }
    else if (intran==34){
        button = gmc.button35;
    }
    else if (intran==35){
        button = gmc.button36;
    }
    else if (intran==36){
        button = gmc.button37;
    }
    else if (intran==37){
        button = gmc.button38;
    }
    else if (intran==38){
        button = gmc.button39;
    }
    else if (intran==39){
        button = gmc.button40;
    }
    else if (intran==40){
        button = gmc.button41;
    }
    else if (intran==41){
        button = gmc.button42;
    }
    else if (intran==42){
        button = gmc.button43;
    }
    else if (intran==43){
        button = gmc.button44;
    }
    else if (intran==44){
        button = gmc.button45;
    }
    else if (intran==45){
        button = gmc.button46;
    }
    else if (intran==46){
        button = gmc.button47;
    }
    else if (intran==47){
        button = gmc.button48;
    }
    else{
        button = gmc.button49;
    }
    return button;
}
+(void)makebuttonsUnpressable{
    GameController *gmc =[[GameController alloc]init];
    gmc.button1.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button2.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button3.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button4.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button5.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button6.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button7.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button8.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button9.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button10.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button11.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button12.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button13.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button14.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button15.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button16.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button17.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button18.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button19.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button20.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button21.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button22.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button23.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button24.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button25.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button26.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button27.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button28.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button29.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button30.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button31.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button32.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button33.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button34.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button35.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button36.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button37.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button38.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button39.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button40.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button41.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button42.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button43.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button44.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button45.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button46.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button47.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button48.enabled=NO;
    gmc.button49.enabled=NO;
     NSLog(@"Buttons became unpressable");
}
+(void)makebuttonsPressable{
    GameController *gmc =[[GameController alloc]init];
    gmc.button1.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button2.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button3.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button4.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button5.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button6.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button7.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button8.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button9.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button10.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button11.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button12.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button13.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button14.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button15.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button16.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button17.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button18.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button19.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button20.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button21.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button22.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button23.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button24.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button25.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button26.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button27.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button28.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button29.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button30.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button31.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button32.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button33.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button34.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button35.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button36.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button37.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button38.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button39.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button40.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button41.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button42.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button43.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button44.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button45.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button46.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button47.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button48.enabled=YES;
    gmc.button49.enabled=YES;
    NSLog(@"Buttons became pressable");
}
@end
```

Comment: OMG! **what is that terrible code?!** is that serious? we are such lucky you shouldn't have dealt with 200 buttons...

Comment: Erm..... so what doesn't work ?

Comment: I am a newbie and I dont know sprite kit so I have to make my game with my own way

Comment: I doesnt set the selected buttons background, doesnt make the buttons unpressable or pressable. @CW0007007

Comment: I suggest learning sprite kit then before trying to make a game. Making a game isn't something you can do quickly @!

Comment: It's not a serious game, I'm just wondering why these codes doesn't work? CW0007007

Comment: Probably irrelevant to your problem but read about `IBOutletCollection` and `Objective-C Fast Enumeration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you go to interact with your buttons you are doing `GameController *gmc =[[GameController alloc]init];`. This is creating a new, *empty*, instance of `GameController` which isn't the one that has the actual buttons you see on screen.

You need to actually get the 'main' or true instance of `GameController` which knows about the buttons on screen.

Generally, this code should be in the `GameController` class rather than in the `GameButtons` class...

Also, as per the commend from @Desdenova check out `IBOutletCollection`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can I get the 'main' instance?

Comment: It looks like `GameController` is calling `GameButtons` so either move the code into `GameController` or pass `self` as a parameter when you call (or, better, use `IBOutletCollection` and pass the array of buttons to act on).

Comment: Thank you guys it fixed the pressability but it still doesn't set the buttons background :) Is still there a problem with instances?

Comment: You added a parameter to each method? It looks like the same problem in each case.

Comment: also when I get the [sender currentTitle] by triggering the 'buttonGame' action, log gives the senders currentTitle as (null). What does it mean? I already connected the IBOutlets and UIButtons.

Comment: What is `currentTitle`? It isn't declared anywhere in your question. Log the sender, what is it?

Comment: I added  it to my project now. Inspiredfrom here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858247/ios-one-ibaction-for-multiple-buttons

Comment: Do your buttons have text or images on them? Log the sender.

Comment: no they don't have any text or images on them. They have just the background images that I added by Interface Builder.

Comment: So there will be no `currentTitle` (read the documentation for what `currentTitle` returns).