# is it possible to assign a switch to a function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one button which will control a timer. I making easy, regular, and hard difficulty. I have created three switches within one button. How would I assign each button to the certain switch? Like func hard$ would be assigned to switch(buttonStatehard).

```
 var buttonStatehard: UISwitch!

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

    //stop within 5 ms
    buttonStatehard.setOn(false, animated: true)
    switch(buttonStatehard){
    case 0:
        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        //buttonStatehard = 1;

        break;

    case 1:
        timer.invalidate()
            if(displayTime.text == stoptimer.text){
            score++
            scoring.text = String(score)
            try = 0
            attempt.text = String(try)

        }

        if(displayTime.text != stoptimer.text){
            try++
            attempt.text = String(try)
            if(try > 2){
                gameOver = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
                gameOver.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
                gameOver.opaque = false
                self.view.addSubview(gameOver)
                //UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations:{
                self.gameOver.frame.size = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)

                //})

                gobutton = UIButton()
                let image = "button.png"
                gobutton.setImage(UIImage(named: image), forState: .Normal)
                gobutton.frame = CGRectMake(135, 300, 95, 95)
                gobutton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                gobutton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                self.view.addSubview(gobutton)
                let horizontalConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint1)

                let verticalConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint2)

                let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 95)
                gobutton.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

                let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 95)
                gobutton.addConstraint(heightConstraint)


                golabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(30, 100, 350, 100))
                golabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                golabel.text = "Game Over"
                golabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                golabel.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold" , size: 50)
                self.view.addSubview(golabel)
                let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
                self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

                let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: -150)
                self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

                score = 0
                scoring.text = String(score)


            }

        }
        //buttonStatehard = 2;
        break;

    case 2:
        timer.invalidate()
       // buttonStatehard = 0;
        displayTime.text = "0.00"
        stoptimer.text = String(format: "%.2f", Double(Int(arc4random_uniform(5)+1)))


    default: break;
    }



    if(scoring.text > best.text){
        best.text = String(score)
        defaults.setObject(self.best.text, forKey: "Score")
    }




    //land within 20 ms


    switch(buttonStateez){

    case 0:
        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        buttonStatehard = 1;

        break;

    case 1:
        timer.invalidate()
        if(displayTime.text == stoptimer.text){
            score++
            scoring.text = String(score)
            try = 0
            attempt.text = String(try)

        }
        /* func puones(sender: UIButton!){
        let a = NSString(string: displayTime.text!).doubleValue
        let b = NSString(string: stoptimer.text!).doubleValue
        if (a-b == 0.02 || b-a == 0.02){
        score++
        scoring.text = String(score)
        try = 0
        attempt.text = String(try)
        }
        }

        let a = NSString(string: displayTime.text!).doubleValue
        let b = NSString(string: stoptimer.text!).doubleValue
        if(a-b == 0.01 || b-a == 0.01) {
        score++
        scoring.text = String(score)
        try = 0
        attempt.text = String(try)
        }
        */

        if(displayTime.text != stoptimer.text){
            try++
            attempt.text = String(try)
            if(try > 2){
                gameOver = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
                gameOver.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
                gameOver.opaque = false
                self.view.addSubview(gameOver)
                //UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations:{
                self.gameOver.frame.size = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)

                //})

                gobutton = UIButton()
                let image = "button.png"
                gobutton.setImage(UIImage(named: image), forState: .Normal)
                gobutton.frame = CGRectMake(135, 300, 95, 95)
                gobutton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                gobutton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                self.view.addSubview(gobutton)
                let horizontalConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint1)

                let verticalConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint2)

                let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 95)
                gobutton.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

                let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 95)
                gobutton.addConstraint(heightConstraint)


                golabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(30, 100, 350, 100))
                golabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                golabel.text = "Game Over"
                golabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                golabel.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold" , size: 50)
                self.view.addSubview(golabel)
                let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
                self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

                let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: -150)
                self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

                score = 0
                scoring.text = String(score)


            }

        }
        buttonStatehard = 2;
        break;

    case 2:
        timer.invalidate()
        buttonStatehard = 0;
        displayTime.text = "0.00"
        stoptimer.text = String(format: "%.2f", Double(Int(arc4random_uniform(5)+1)))


    default: break;
    }



    if(scoring.text > best.text){
        best.text = String(score)
        defaults.setObject(self.best.text, forKey: "Score")
    }



    //stop within 10 ms

    switch(buttonStatereg){
    case 0:
        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        buttonStatehard = 1;

        break;

    case 1:
        timer.invalidate()
        if(displayTime.text == stoptimer.text){
            score++
            scoring.text = String(score)
            try = 0
            attempt.text = String(try)

        }
        /* func puones(sender: UIButton!){
        let a = NSString(string: displayTime.text!).doubleValue
        let b = NSString(string: stoptimer.text!).doubleValue
        if (a-b == 0.02 || b-a == 0.02){
        score++
        scoring.text = String(score)
        try = 0
        attempt.text = String(try)
        }
        }

        let a = NSString(string: displayTime.text!).doubleValue
        let b = NSString(string: stoptimer.text!).doubleValue
        if(a-b == 0.01 || b-a == 0.01) {
        score++
        scoring.text = String(score)
        try = 0
        attempt.text = String(try)
        }
        */

        if(displayTime.text != stoptimer.text){
            try++
            attempt.text = String(try)
            if(try > 2){
                gameOver = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
                gameOver.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
                gameOver.opaque = false
                self.view.addSubview(gameOver)
                //UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations:{
                self.gameOver.frame.size = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)

                //})

                gobutton = UIButton()
                let image = "button.png"
                gobutton.setImage(UIImage(named: image), forState: .Normal)
                gobutton.frame = CGRectMake(135, 300, 95, 95)
                gobutton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                gobutton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                self.view.addSubview(gobutton)
                let horizontalConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint1)

                let verticalConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint2)

                let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 95)
                gobutton.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

                let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gobutton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 95)
                gobutton.addConstraint(heightConstraint)


                golabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(30, 100, 350, 100))
                golabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                golabel.text = "Game Over"
                golabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                golabel.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold" , size: 50)
                self.view.addSubview(golabel)
                let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
                self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

                let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: -150)
                self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

                score = 0
                scoring.text = String(score)


            }

        }
        buttonStatehard = 2;
        break;

    case 2:
        timer.invalidate()
        buttonStatehard = 0;
        displayTime.text = "0.00"
        stoptimer.text = String(format: "%.2f", Double(Int(arc4random_uniform(5)+1)))


    default: break;
    }



    if(scoring.text > best.text){
        best.text = String(score)
        defaults.setObject(self.best.text, forKey: "Score")
    }




}
```

How would I assign each button to the certain switch?

```
func ez$ (sender: UIButton!){

}

func reg$ (sender: UIButton!){

}

func hard$ (sender: UIButton!){
    buttonStatehard.setOn(true, animated:true)

    //error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
}
```

Comment: By adding <onclick> inside the button.

Comment: what would <onclick> do?

Comment: That way you can trigger the button for the certain switch.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the line of code for <onclick> is there a website you can refer me to?

Comment: Oh you're using Swift aren't you..? I'll do a quick research and let you know.

Comment: That's some horrible code you got going on there...

Comment: @joethemow The `buttonStatehard` is an Int not `UISwitch`, why did you call `setOn`?

Comment: yeah I just realized it was an Int. What would I call rather than `setOn`

Comment: @joethemow Could be that the `buttonStatehard` is nil, so you're getting the error

Comment: Yeah I changed the location of the `buttonStatehard.setOn(false, animated: true)` to the viewdidLoad becuase the button state is only false when button is clicked so I moved it so that every time the app opens it will be false, but I am still getitng the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error @Bannings

Comment: @joethemow Did you initialize the buttonStatehard?

Comment: yes `var buttonStatehard: UISwitch!`

Comment: http://puu.sh/iKEvq/029db3fc39.png

Comment: @joethemow No... Trying to change it `var buttonStatehard: UISwitch!` to `var buttonStatehard = UISwitch()`

Comment: It stopped crashing but since I changed it to a switch I cannot use the statement `buttonStatehard = 1`, and that is needed for the timer to work

Comment: @joethemow Do you mean of that `case 0` and `case 1`?

Comment: no they are commented out in the code above, butI specifically mean `buttonStatehard = 1`

Comment: @joethemow Why are you set the `buttonStatehard` to 1? You could use `buttonStatehard.on = true`

Comment: Every click will increment it. If you look further then it will show that `buttonStatehard = 2`

Comment: It's what starts, stops, and resets the timer

Comment: @joethemow So why do you need that `UISwitch`? Can you post your project on anywhere?

Comment: @Bannings I have one timer. I am making a game where the user chooses easy, regular, or hard. Based on what the user chooses, each difficulty will have it's own parameters. Under the IBAction, i just put three switches, but in order to do that I need to take out `buttonStatehard = 1...2...0` but this is required for the timer to work.

Comment: @joethemow It seems you have three buttons which correspond to easy, regular and hard, then there is one variable that remember what the user chosen difficulty. So you have to set the variable's value into different value(e.g. 0,1,2) in `ez`, `reg`, `hard` functions. So you don't need the `UISwitch` at all. You need only one `switch` statement for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found this for you, comment if it's not what you're looking for.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if mySwitch.on {
        myTextField.text = "The Switch is Off"
        println("Switch is on")
        mySwitch.setOn(false, animated:true)
    } else {
          myTextField.text = "The Switch is On"
          mySwitch.setOn(true, animated:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error the `if mySwitch.on`....'Int' does not have a member named "on".

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Hmm perhaps the code isn't compatible with the old version.

Comment: if I may ask, what did you search?

Comment: This one i shared above is just an example, it's not adapted to your code. I searched for your problem.

Comment: oh ok, any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Hi for add switch case in Button click you can refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858247/ios-one-ibaction-for-multiple-buttons